# Not able to drag window *UP* to second monitor on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I've got a wireless HDMI connection from my Mac OSX mini display port to my tv in my room.

Visually, the TV is "above" my laptop. I set up the System Preferences/Display/Arrangement to have the second monitor above my main laptop screen.

However, the top ("File") menu bar seems to be stopping me from dragging windows up to that monitor.

My solution is to set the second monitor on the left or the right, so when I drag it to the left, say, the window shows up above my screen on the second monitor.

Is there any way I could drag windows up *through* the File Menu bar on top of the OSX screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The menu bar prevents windows from passing through it. In the Arrangement tab, click and drag the menu bar to the secondary display.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a window that is maximized already on your second monitor, you can't move up a window from your macbook native screen.

Comment: Who at Apple thought this was a good idea?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an external monitor at the moment to test the problem with, but I have used a setup somewhat like this in the past, and I know that a secondary screen above the primary one does still allow moving windows onto it.

There is a rule that the title bar of a window may not be obscured, either by being offscreen or underneath the menu bar. I'm guessing that your TV is lower resolution than your main screen. Try making sure that the window is *small enough* to fit in the width of the TV before dragging it up.